# Decent pattern for testable async operations?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns, asynchronous

I had trouble finding a simple, flexible pattern to allow me to write code in my ViewModels that in runtime would run asynchronously but during test-time run synchronously.  This is what I came up with - does anyone have any suggestions?  Is this a good path to go down?  Are there better existing patterns out there?

**LongRunningCall definition:**

```
public class LongRunningCall
{
    public Action ExecuteAction { get; set; }
    public Action PostExecuteAction { get; set; }

    public LongRunningCall(Action executeAction = null, Action postExecuteAction = null)
    {
        ExecuteAction = executeAction;
        PostExecuteAction = postExecuteAction;
    }

    public void Execute(Action<Exception> onError)
    {
        try
        {
            ExecuteAction();
            PostExecuteAction();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (onError == null)
                throw;
            onError(ex);
        }
    }

    public void ExecuteAsync(TaskScheduler scheduler, Action<Exception> onError)
    {
        var executeTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(ExecuteAction);
        var postExecuteTask = executeTask.ContinueWith((t) =>
            {
                if (t.Exception != null)
                    throw t.Exception;
                PostExecuteAction();
            }, scheduler);
        if (onError != null)
            postExecuteTask.ContinueWith((t) => { onError(t.Exception); });
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var continueCall = new LongRunningCall(continueCommand_Execute, continueCommand_PostExecute);
if (svc.IsAsyncRequired)
   continueCall.ExecuteAsync(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(), continueCommand_Error);
else
   continueCall.Execute(continueCommand_Error);
```

The only real pre-requisite is that you need to know at runtime if you're supposed to use async/sync.  When I run my unit tests I send in a mock that tells my code to run synchronously, when the application actually runs IsAsyncRequired defaults to true;

Feedback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to encapsulate the decision on whether to execute code synchronously or asynchronously in a separate class that can be abstracted behind an interface such as this:

```
public interface ITaskExecuter
{
    void ScheduleTask(
        Action executeAction,
        Action postExecuteAction,
        Action<Exception> onException);
}
```

An instance of a class implementing `ITaskExecuter` can be injected where required.
You can inject different instances for testing versus production scenarios.

Usage becomes:

```
taskExecuter.ScheduleTask(
    continueCommand_Execute,
    continueCommand_PostExecute,
    continueCommand_Error);
```

with no separate code paths in the calling class for test versus production.

You have the option of writing tests that:

- just check the correct actions are passed to the task executer, or
- configuring the task executer to execute the action synchronously and
  test for the desired result, or
- do both.

Comment: How would I modify the code to optionally take parameters?  Do I have to duplicate the ITaskExecutor & its implementations with ITaskExecutor<T> and ScheduleTask(Func<T> executeAction, Action<T> postExecuteAction, etc...?  Is there a way to make my TaskExecutor generic enough to handle any set of parameters like Task<> does without having to make that many definitions?

Comment: I had imagined you would supply the execute action and post-execute actions as anonymous delegates that already had any parameters included, and they'd both be of type `Action`. E.g. `taskExecuter.ScheduleTask(() => MyTask(1, 2.3f, "whatever"), () => MyPostTask(true, false, "etc."), e => MyExceptionHandler(e));`

Answer (score 2):

I did something very simmilar at my current job, but can't get to the code to copy/paste it right now...

Basically what I did was to create an `IWorker` interface, with a `DoWork(Func<>)` method.

Then I created 2 derived classes, one 'AsyncWorker' and one 'SyncWorker'.  The SyncWorker just executes the passed in `Func` (synchronously), and the 'AsyncWorker' is a wrapper around a `BackgroundWorker` that sends the passed in `Func` off to the BackgroundWorker to be processed asynchronously.

Then, I changed my ViewModel to have an `IWorker` passed in. This moves the dependency resolution out of the ViewModel, so you can use a Dep. Inj. utility (I use Unity and Constructor injection).

Since I use Unity, in my unit test configuration, I then map `IWorker` to `SyncWorker`, and in production I map `IWorker` to `AsyncWorker`.

Hope that makes sense... I know it'd be easier if I had the code on hand...

Comment: This is the same solution I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing `ExecuteAsync` so that it will return a `Task`:

```
public Task ExecuteAsync(TaskScheduler scheduler, Action<Exception> onError)
```

So in production code, I would just call it as is:

```
longRunningCall.ExecuteAsync(
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(),
    continueCommand_Error);
```

But in unit tests, I would wait for the task to actually finish:

```
var task = longRunningCall.ExecuteAsync(
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(),
    continueCommand_Error);
task.Wait();
```